# How can align the bottom in TableRow?

Tags: android

At present, textView1 and imageViewSamll are the top aligned, how can I make textView1 align the bottom  of imageViewSamll?

Thanks!

```
   <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
             android:text="@string/Thumbnail" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSamll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </TableRow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/Thumbnail" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSamll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place both in a `RelativeLayout`.

`RelativeLayout` has many alignment properties available.

You can add `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageViewSamll"` to `TextViews`'s attributes.